# 4 [main] open mchess 8784 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to mchess.exe.stackdumpfile

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

I am trying to make a simple chess engine using the alpha-beta buring
To avoid the threefold repetition I made second_best so it will be returned, if the threefold repetition is growing up, I can't figure out where is the problem causing the error but I believe it is in the ai.cc file because the code worked just fine before I edited it.

but i don't see why or how I solve it?

**ai.cc**:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // exit()
#include "ai.h"
#include "CMoveList.h"

/*
* zero, if the position is equal.
* 900+, if the opponent is check-mated.
* -999, if the side to move is check-mated.
*/

int AI::search(int alpha, int beta, int level)
{
    if (level == 0)
        return m_board.get_value(); // We are at leaf, just return the static evaluation.

    CMoveList moves;
    m_board.find_legal_moves(moves);
    int best_val = -999; // Assume the worst

                         // Search through all legal moves
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<moves.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (best_val >= beta)
        {
            // This is the alpha-beta pruning.
            // Stop searching, if we already have found a "killer" move.
            break;
        }
        if (best_val > alpha)
        {
            // This is part of the alpha-beta pruning too.
            // Tighten the search window.
            alpha = best_val;
        }
        CMove move = moves[i];
        // Do a recursive search
        m_board.make_move(move);
        CMoveList tempMoves;
        m_board.find_legal_moves(tempMoves);

        bool checkMate = m_board.isKingInCheck();
        int num;
        if (tempMoves.size() == 0)
        {
            if (checkMate)
            {
                return 900 + level;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            num = -search(-beta, -alpha, level - 1);
        }
        m_board.undo_move(move);

        if (num > best_val)
        {
            // Store the best value so far.
            best_val = num;
        }
    }

    return best_val;
} // end of int search

  /***************************************************************
  * find_best_move
  *
  * This is the main AI.
  * It returns what it considers to be the best legal move in the
  * current position.
  ***************************************************************/
CMove AI::find_best_move()
{
    // Make a list of all legal moves
    CMoveList moves;
    m_board.find_legal_moves(moves);


    std::cout << "info string " << moves.size() << " legal moves." << std::endl;

    CMoveList best_moves; // Array of the (one or more) best moves so far
    int best_val = -999;
    CMove best_move;
    CMove second_best = moves[0];
    // Search through all legal moves
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<moves.size(); ++i)
    {
        CMove move = moves[i];

        // Get value of current move
        m_board.make_move(move);
        CMoveList tempMoves;
        m_board.find_legal_moves(tempMoves);
        bool checkMate = m_board.isKingInCheck();
        int val;
        if (tempMoves.size() == 0 && checkMate)
        {
            m_board.undo_move(move);
            return move;
        }
        else
        {
            val = -search(-999, 999, 4);
        }
        m_board.undo_move(move);

        std::cout << "info string " << val << " : " << move << std::endl;

        if (val > best_val)
        {
            second_best = best_moves[rand() % best_moves.size()];
            best_val = val;
            best_moves.clear();
            best_moves.push_back(move);
        }
        else if (val == best_val)
        {
            best_moves.push_back(move);
        }
    }

    if (best_moves.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "BUG: No legal moves!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int size = best_moves.size();
    int index = rand() % size;
    best_move = best_moves[index];
    if (m_board.get_threefoldRepitationDraw() > 2)
    {
        if (size > 1)
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                index--;
            }
            best_move = best_moves[index];
        }
        else
        {
            best_move = second_best;
        }
    }
    return best_move;
} // end of find_best_move
```

**The error:**

```
4 [main] open mchess 8784 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to mchess.exe.stackdumpfile
```

**Stack trace:**

```
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFBD60  0018005FAE9 (00000000000, 000FFFFCE00, 000FFFFBF68, 000FFFFDE50)
00000000002  0018006195A (00000000064, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFC040  00180125D3B (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFC320  0018012231E (00000000080, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFC490  00180122814 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000006)
000FFFFC490  00180122A59 (7FFA8A4E5012, 00000004048, 0018022F508, 00180127E5C)
000FFFFC490  00180122D3F (0010040A180, 0010040A190, 000000003CD, 0018022F48F)
000FFFFC490  00180043395 (0000000003F, 0000000001E, 55854FFFC57, 00B00000009)
000FFFFFFFF  00100408683 (001FFFFFFF6, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFFF  0010040332D (00100406AD8, 001802441A0, FFFFFFFF00074940, 000FFFFC60B)
000FFFFCB40  001004034ED (00100000001, 000FFFFC6EB, 03600000000, 000FFFFC710)
000000003A9  00100406A2A (FFFFFFFFFFFFD680, 000FFFFC7CB, 00000000001, 000000003A6)
000FFFFFC56  00100406A63 (001800F64B0, 000FFFFC8AB, 02400000002, 000FFFFC8D0)
000000003A9  00100406A63 (00080210890, 00000000000, 00000000003, 00600095240)
000FFFFFC19  00100406F74 (00180198441, 00000000002, 0018014BC59, 003F8990F40)
003F89EC560  001004083C4 (00000000020, FF0700010302FF00, 00180049DAA, 00000000000)
```

End of stack trace (more stack frames may be present)

The original code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // exit()
#include "ai.h"
#include "CMoveList.h"

int AI::search(int alpha, int beta, int level)
{
    if (level == 0)
        return m_board.get_value(); 

    CMoveList moves;
    m_board.find_legal_moves(moves);
    int best_val = -999; 
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<moves.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (best_val >= beta)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (best_val > alpha)
        {
            alpha = best_val;
        }
        const CMove& move = moves[i];
        if (move.is_captured_piece_a_king())
        {
        return 900 + level;
        }
        m_board.make_move(move);
        int num = -search(-beta, -alpha, level-1);
        m_board.undo_move(move);

        if (num > best_val)
        {
            best_val = num;
        }
    }
    return best_val;
} 

CMove AI::find_best_move()
{
    CMoveList moves;
    m_board.find_legal_moves(moves);
    std::cout << "info string " << moves.size() << " legal moves." << std::endl;
    CMoveList best_moves; // Array of the (one or more) best moves so far
    int best_val = -999;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<moves.size(); ++i)
    {
        CMove move = moves[i];
        m_board.make_move(move);
        int val = -search(-999, 999, 4);
        m_board.undo_move(move); 
        std::cout << "info string " << val << " : " << move << std::endl;
        if (val > best_val)
        {
            best_val = val;
            best_moves.clear();
            best_moves.push_back(move);
        }
        else if (val == best_val)
        {
            best_moves.push_back(move);
        }
    }
    if (best_moves.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "BUG: No legal moves!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return best_moves[rand() % best_moves.size()];
}
```

I would appreciate any help since I didn't find useful online.
Thanks

Comment: Please post the full error (including the full stack trace).

Comment: Also compare original file with your modification

Comment: Please, paste the full error message instead of a link to an image. Also, the error happens in code you didn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that best_moves list was empty so its size was zero, and it was trying to get rand() % zero so the exception happened